# Angular autoscroll after API call because of button position

Tags: css, angular, click

I have the following issue:

I have a button that should be in the right bottom corner of a page. So the button's CSS properties are:

```
.mybutton {
  z-index: 99999991;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}


<button *ngIf="logistic.getPermission('open_shipment_button')" class="btn btn-secondary mybutton" type="button" (click)="openOSP($event)">Open Shipment Pool
    <span *ngIf="draggables?.length > 0" class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
      {{draggables?.length}}
      <span class="visually-hidden">unread messages</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

The parent div of the button does not have any specific properties.

- I click this button (it does not matter what it does, because even when i comment out everything inside this click function the issue appears)
- I then do something else that resolves in an API call that i process using the subscribe function on an obeservable. During that API call my page autoscrolls to the very bottom. However, this only happens when i clicked the button beforehands. Also i removed the "position: fixed" property and replaced it with relative. Then of course the button is not in the right bottom corner anymore but the autoscroll does not happen anymore.

What is the problem? Why does it autoscroll to the bottom and how can i prevent this?

Comment: Is it an actual `button` element? Or perhaps some `<a href="#..." class="mybutton"`, which I could imagine triggers some scrolling-mechanism globally enabled for in-page anchors ...?

Comment: I edited the question and added the code for the button, which is an actual button element.